# How to add class names to tr and td in multiple tables with conditions?

Tags: javascript

I hope you're all doing well.

I have multiple `table`s, all of them have "table" class and without IDs.

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 1, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 1, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 2, Column 2</td>
            <td>Table 2, Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 3, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 2</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 3</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Please help me with adding class names to table cells (`td`) with some conditions.**

- I need to add Bootstrap classes `col col-md-6` to all `td`s if there are 2 `td`s in a row (`tr`).
- I need to add Bootstrap classes `col col-md-6 col-md-4` to all `td`s if there are 3 `td`s in a row (`tr`).
- I need to add Bootstrap classes `col col-md-6 col-md-3` to all `td`s if there are 4 `td`s in a row (`tr`).

Also, if you don't mind helping with adding a simple class name `row` to `tr`s.

*For some reason, I can't manually do this or even change the `table`s to `div`s.*

Thank you so much and have a wonderful day/night!

Comment: Why  do you want to combine tables with cols styles, why not use just cols only?

Comment: @Bharat I'm using Flextype CMS. There's no option to create custom layouts (e.g. 2 columns in a row) and the only option I have in mind is by using ```table``` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setClass(el, className, fn){
  if(el) {
    for (var i of el) {
      if(typeof className === "string")
         i.setAttribute("class", className);
      if(fn) fn(i);
    }
  }
}
var t = document.getElementsByClassName("table");
setClass(t, null, function(i) {
    let tr = i.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    //row > tr
    setClass(tr, "row", function(q) {
        let td = q.getElementsByTagName("td");
        //td > classNames
        if(td.length === 2) 
            setClass(td, "col col-md-6")
        else if(td.length === 3) 
             setClass(td, "col col-md-6 col-md-4")
        else if(td.length === 4) 
             setClass(td, "col col-md-6 col-md-3 ")
    });
})
```

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 1, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 1, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 1, Column 3</td>
            <td>Table 1, Column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 2, Column 2</td>
            <td>Table 2, Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 3, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 2</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 3</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A little typo:
The ```col-md-4``` should be ```col-lg-4```. Same to ```col-md-3``` should be ```col-lg-3``` but overall this answer is great!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way, can we improvised

```js
function applyStyle(tds, className){
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].className += (tds[i].className ? " " : "") + className
  }
}

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  var table = tables[i];
  var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
  switch(tds.length){
    case 2:
      applyStyle(tds,"col col-md-6");
    break;
    case 3:
      applyStyle(tds,"col-md-4");
    break;
    case 4:
      applyStyle(tds,"col-md-3");
    break;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="matrix">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 1, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 1, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 2, Column 2</td>
            <td>Table 2, Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 3, Column 1</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 2</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 3</td>
            <td>Table 3, Column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I edited your answer and wrote `tr.className` instead of `tr[q].className` edit it after accepting the editation and also replace `vat` with `var`

Comment: @JS_INF, didnt get this part, where did you update this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you mention, from where your table is generating. I mean is it a static table or dynamic.

If it is static then I think you know the answer. In another case, while rendering the table from any data source you need to check the length first, and while iterating each table you need to check td under them using jq selector something like

$(this.table.td).length()

where this is the current item under the loop.

Mention a more detailed cases of your, SO that I can precisely provide a code snippet.

Comment: It's dynamically generated by Flextype CMS.

Comment: Do we have control there to write our code while generating these table structure?

Comment: Yes, we're able to write our code to the theme files.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.table').each(function( index ) {
        var ColumnCount = $(this).find('tr td').length;
        if(ColumnCount == 2){
            $(this).find('tr td').each(function(){

                $(this).addClass('col col-md-6');
            });
        }
        if(ColumnCount == 3){
            $(this).find('tr td').each(function(){

                $(this).addClass('col col-md-6 col-md-4');
            });
        }
        if(ColumnCount == 4){
            $(this).find('tr td').each(function(){

                $(this).addClass('col col-md-6 col-md-3');
            });
        }
    });
```